# BSON::ObjectId vs Mongo::ObjectID

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems, bson

In [online API](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.5.2/) they are referring to `Mongo::ObjectID`.

I have `require 'mongo'` but still ruby fails to find it. For instance, I need to find an object by its Id and I'm doing:

```
mongo_db['post'].find({_id: Mongo::ObjectID(params[:id])}).next
```

and it seems that it can't find Mongo::ObjectID and results in: ``` NoMethodError - undefined method ``ObjectID' for Mongo:Module: ```

So after some time I started to `require 'bson'` and doing

```
mongo_db['post'].find({_id: BSON::ObjectId(params[:id])}).next
```

and it worked!

So what's the difference between BSON::ObjectId and Mongo::ObjectID and what do I need to do to make the latter one work (and do I really need to)?

PS: I've got

```
bson (1.5.2, 1.4.1)
    Authors: Jim Menard, Mike Dirolf, Kyle Banker
    Homepage: http://www.mongodb.org
    Installed at (1.5.2): /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1
                 (1.4.1): /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1

    Ruby implementation of BSON

mongo (1.5.2, 1.4.1)
    Authors: Jim Menard, Mike Dirolf, Kyle Banker
    Homepage: http://www.mongodb.org
    Installed at (1.5.2): /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1
                 (1.4.1): /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1

    Ruby driver for the MongoDB
```

Comment: The only mentions of "ObjectID" in the mongo gem are in the documentation so I suspect that `Mongo::ObjectID` is some leftover from older versions and no one updated the documentation; I only checked 1.5.2 and 1.3.1 as that's all I had around. I use BSON::ObjectId in my MongoDB stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes to the Ruby driver that are relevant here.  The first is:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-158

That moved the ObjectID to the "camel case" version ObjectId.  The switch from the Mongo namespace to the BSON namespace happened far earlier (0.2), see the last entry in the History file here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/docs/HISTORY.md

The real problem, of course, is old and crufty documentation, so I have submitted a pull request to update it:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/pull/90

Comment: just to note - pull request has been merged - woo!