# What is the difference between mongo ObjectID, ObjectId & Mongoose ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't figure out the difference between mongo ObjectID & ObjectId.
The document said [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), but when I read the code, I see

```
import { ObjectID } from 'bson';
```

To make things even more confused is the mongoose document & code. 
The mongoose also says ObjectId http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js. But when I read the codes I saw

```
// mongodb.ObjectID does not allow mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id). This is
//   commonly used in mongoose and is found in an example in the docs:
//   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate
// constructor exposes static methods of mongodb.ObjectID and ObjectId(id)
type ObjectIdConstructor = typeof mongodb.ObjectID & {
  (s?: string | number): mongodb.ObjectID;
}
```

So what exactly is the difference between ObjectID, ObjectId and mongoose ObjectId?

I found there was another SO talking about this  [BSON::ObjectId vs Mongo::ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386533/bsonobjectid-vs-mongoobjectid)

The links there were dead though and it didn't take about mongoose. So I hope my question won't be marked as duplicated.

Comment: There isn't really any intrinsic difference other than the mongoose import being essentially a "wrapped type" much as is shown in the code you reference, and that's basically related to "type casting" since various mongoose methods allow you to specify a "string" value which will then be internally "cast" to an `ObjectID`. Point being that `Schema.Types.ObjectId` means something to defined mongoose schemas. But the underlying data ( and in fact the actual implementation ) is simply the same.

Comment: But what about mongo ObjectID & ObjectId, same ?

Comment: Yes it's the same. As you can see in the code the import comes from "bson" as the library. The same is true in the core driver. And going back to the answer you referenced, over time all language implementations have split out the "BSON" parts from the core driver as a separate dependency. In fact the BSON library for JavaScript works perfectly fine in a browser even. So there is no difference, it's just "implementing" the common library method in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo ObjectID is a unique 12-byte identifier which can be generated by MongoDB as the primary key.

An ObjectID is a unique, not null integer field used to uniquely identify rows in tables

In Mongoose ObjectID is same as Mongo ObjectID and referencing an object in another collection

Answer (score 0):

1. `ObjectID`: This is the BSON ObjectID datatype that MongoDB uses. It's a 12-byte identifier typically made up of a timestamp, machine identifier, process id, and a counter. This is provided by the native MongoDB driver for Node.js.
2. `ObjectId`: This is often seen in the MongoDB shell and it is essentially the same as `ObjectID`. It's just a different naming convention. When you're working in the MongoDB shell, you'll use `ObjectId`. But in a Node.js environment using the MongoDB native driver, you'll use `ObjectID`.
3. `Mongoose ObjectId`: Mongoose is a MongoDB object modeling tool designed to work in an asynchronous environment. Mongoose provides a straight-forward, schema-based solution to model your application data with MongoDB. The `ObjectId` in Mongoose is essentially the same as `ObjectID` in the MongoDB native driver for Node.js. Mongoose just provides an extra layer of convenience and added functionality.

In summary, these three terms are essentially referring to the same thing but are used in slightly different contexts (MongoDB shell vs. Node.js environment vs. Mongoose environment).